# convert the string to specific datetime format with strptime in c++

Tags: c++

```
        I have a string in format Date Time 20160524T154628
        Now want the values in terms::hr :: 15,mm:: 46,ss :: 28,month:: 05,year:: 2016,day:: 24

 string convertstring(*str1)
    {
         struct tm t;
          strptime(sr1, "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S", &t);
        char buffer[256];
          strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%F %T", &t);
    string str2(buffer);
    return str2;

    }
```

Comment: So this is not what the strftime format string gives, you. But could you please format the wanted output with a bit more effort, to make clear, what You actually want to achieve (and maybe show the output of your trial code (return value?). Think that would help us help you. THanks.

Comment: This is the output I m getting::date time as :: 39042-11-7988232 5335636:812640520:01

Comment: Claro, the code does not even compile on my settings. Just hacking into runnable state would be good. Minimum: `std::string convertstring(std::string str1)`, and `strptime(str1.c_str(), ...` (sr1 is not known ;-), and of course `#include <ctime>` to make strptime and friends known. Next I'd suggest to read the strptime signature, to understand, why `str1.c_str()` is a viable argument ... what you are getting is random bytes interpreted as typed content, I guess. Happy hacking. And finally strftime format strings. Questions with a working main ready to run are always a better way ...

Answer (score 1):

Using this [modern (C++11/14), free open-source date/time/timezone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

std::string
convertstring(const std::string& str1)
{
    std::istringstream buf{str1};
    date::local_seconds t;
    date::parse(buf, "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S", t);
    if (buf.fail())
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not parse " + str1);
    return date::format("%F %T", t);
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << convertstring("20160524T154628") << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2016-05-24 15:46:28
```

Now you can do date/time handling with a modern C++ API, instead of with an ancient C API.  There's much more here than just parsing and formatting.